# Docusaurus v2 - recent blogs list for homepage

Tags: docusaurus

in Docusaurus v2 is there a way to generate a list of recent blogs that can then be used to populate a block on the front page (`src/pages/index.js`)? I'm thinking something similar to how the `features` list which is then set by `<Feature ... />`.

In Docusaurus v1, this was accomplashied by the code below but I can't find a simple way to get the list of all blog posts equivalent to `MetadataBlog`

```js
const MetadataBlog = require("../../core/MetadataBlog.js");
...
<h2>Latest Blog Posts</h2>
<ul>
  {MetadataBlog.slice(0, 5).map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      <a href={`/blog/${item.path}`}>{item.title}</a>{" "}
        <small>
          {new Date(item.date).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
            weekday: undefined,
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric"
          })}
        </small>
      </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Having dug around the code a bit, I believe I just want to be able to call the `generateBlogPosts` junction from `@docusaurus/plugin-content-blog/lib/blogUtils.js`. Any pointers on how I can call that function from `src/pages/index.js`? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to hack this together with a slight change to the OP code:

```js
const recentPosts = require("../../.docusaurus/docusaurus-plugin-content-blog/default/blog-post-list-prop-default.json");

<ul>
  {recentPosts.items.slice(0, 5).map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      <a href={`${item.permalink}`}>{item.title}</a>{" "}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

It seems to work, although it depends on internals that might change.

Answer (score 0):

There's no elegant way as of now I'm afraid. You could write your own plugin that is similar to the blog plugin and pull the most recent pages and generate a JSON file to be imported on the index page.